# Android Studio Secondary Click Not Working

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, click

I just installed Android Studio to my new Mac book and somehow the secondary click is not working only when I use the option "Click or Tap with Two Fingers". **This only happens in Android Studio.**

I can use secondary click by tapping with two fingers from other apps.
I can also use secondary click by click in the bottom right corner.

[image]

Specs:

- Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
- Macbook Pro M2

Added information:

- Formatted and re-installed the Android Studio, it's still not working
- Secondary click with clicking with two fingers works but tapping with two fingers still doesn't work (only in Android Studio)

Comment: I unfortunately have no solution to this problem, but I can confirm I have the same problem on my Macbook Pro M2. It seems to be related to the M2 or MacOS Ventura, because it stopped working also in Arctic Fox, and upgrading to Electric Eel did not help. This should probably be reported as a bug on AndroidStudio and/or IntelliJ

Comment: @OlofHedman Thanks Olof for the confirmation. I was wondered whether this only happens to me. Reporting a bug on Android Studio sounds right to me.

Comment: Same problem facing with M2 Pro Max :)

Comment: Same for me, on 14 inch M2 Pro

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. If you select click with tap, for the second click you must press don't tap.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have any references for the bug, possibly from AS issue tracker, you should include them in your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem.
Android Studio Electric Eel + Macbook Air M2 (Monterey).
The Trackpad Secondary Click setting *Click or Tap with Two Fingers* is not working.

Change Secondary Click to ***Click in bottom right corner*** or ***Click in bottom left corner***.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Macbook air M2 and Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Build
#AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023

But now after upgrading to Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023

the issue seems to be solved :-)